# Errors when executing commands with zsh (Erros ao efetuar comandos com o zsh)

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I execute a command in `zsh`, it appears here and the given command does not continue...

```sh
spaceship_exec_time_preexec_hook:2: command not found: date
zsh: command not found: code
spaceship_jobs:3: command not found: awk                                        
spaceship_jobs:3: command not found: wc
spaceship_jobs:3: command not found: tr
```

I can't do it `nano ~ / .zshrc` too.

Comment: It just means that your PATH is not correctly set. For getting things operational in your current shell, do a `export PATH=.....` manually and then look at the relevant dot files in your home directory, which one fiddles with the PATH and ruins it. The most likely candidates are `.zshenv`, `.zshlogin` and `.zshrc`. See the section _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_ in the zsh man page for a list of all files involved in a zsh startup.

Comment: Even if your PATH is broken, you can invoke `nano` by specifying the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
zsh -f
```

It will load zsh with no config at all. If your commands work after starting zsh this way you will know that you have some issues on your `~/.zshrc`